# .Clear Vs .Delete to reduce document size - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Guys which of the below in better to be used in order to reduce document size?

`.Clear`

`.Delete`

Have in mind that worksheet includes a variety of formats (cell fill with colors, hyperlinks, bolds etc)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. Following is my test and observation.

I populated entire column A and saved workbook. Size is `5556 KB`.

I used `Delete` method

`Range("A524288:A1048576").Delete xlUp`

After saving, workbook size is `2784 KB`.

Then I used `Clear` as below

`Range("A524288:A1048576").Clear`

After saving, workbook size is `2784 KB` i.e. exactly the same. So no impact on the size of workbook in this particular case!